# How do I fix 'Source not found' error when debugging in Eclipse, using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm practicing building a test automation framework using Selenium Webdrive in Eclipse with Java, and as part of this I'm debugging through the code I have written so that I have a full understanding (I should note that when I run my tests outside of debug mode they work fine). The issue I have is that I keep encountering 'Source not found' errors in debug mode in respect of a whole load of stuff.

I've attached a screenshot below which shows my debug window in Eclipse, and shows an example of one of the errors.
[image]

So, the situation is that I have my TestRunner class from where I am running my tests (see code below)

```
package dataStructureModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    List<iTest> tests = new ArrayList<iTest>();

    // adding first test
    tests.add((iTest) new DragDefaultTest001());

    // adding second test
    tests.add((iTest) new ColorCheckTest002());

    BREAKPOINT HERE!
    for(int i = 0; i < tests.size() ; i++)
    {
        iTest currentTest = tests.get(i);
        currentTest.testSetup(driver);
        boolean testResult = currentTest.runTest();
        if(testResult)
        {
            System.out.println(currentTest.testName() + " test passed.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(currentTest.testName() + " test failed.");
        }
        currentTest.testCleanup();
    }   
   }

}
```

I've set a breakpoint at the 'for' loop to iterate through my tests (I've not attached the code, given that as mentioned earlier, the tests do run). The Firefox browser loads up and I start stepping through and all looks good. Then I hit one of these 'Source not found' errors', of which there are many. I've attached a screenshot here, which gives an example....https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu2Od.png

I know it asks to 'Edit Source Lookup Path', but I'm not sure what I should be referencing? As far as I'm aware I've attached all the selenium jar files, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hello Andy, Can you please show the existing libraries referenced by the project?

Comment: Hey there, I've attached a screenshot for you....http://imgur.com/SajzhRQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs selenium-jar SOURCE files. In case you do no intend to see internals of Selenium Jars(which is a rare case), then just Step Over(F6) instead of Step Into(F5)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sakshi, that's great, your solution has helped! The 'source not found' errors I was getting were in relation to external libraries which I didn't need to debug. Therefore, by doing what you suggested and stepping over these external libraries I could concentrate on just the areas where I had written code. Thanks again!