# Click on Tabs in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

[image]I am trying to open different section of page. These Section will open on click of different tabs. 
Below is HTML Structure of Page

```
<div id="MainContentPlaceHolder_divMainContent">
<div id="MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase" class="Tab ajax__tab_container ajax__tab_default" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible;">
<div id="MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_header" class="ajax__tab_header">
<span id="MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlCaseDetails_tab" class="ajax__tab_active">
<span id="MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle_tab" class="ajax__tab_hover">
<span class="ajax__tab_outer">
<span class="ajax__tab_inner">
<a id="__tab_MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle" class="ajax__tab_tab" style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">
<span>Vehicle</span>
</a>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

and I have Written Below Lines but these are not working

```
driver.findElement(By.id("__tab_MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Vehicle']")).click();
```

I got **Source Not Found Error**

Comment: As I can see your second xpath is wrong. Use //span[text()='Vehicle'] instead

Comment: @J.Lyu thanks. I corrected code. after change i didn't got any error but selenium is not triggering to tab(no action is happening)

Comment: May I have your actual page URL? So that I am able to have a test.

Comment: @J.Lyu sorry Lyu..It's a company Project. I can't post credentials  publically

Comment: Click on element is firing a javascript function?

Comment: @RahilKumar  Ok. Firstly by output the **attributes** of the found element to make sure it's a correct one. Secondly, I see that href='#' so it was maybe triggered by Javascript, so try to set **Javascript** enabled property as true; Thirdly, you may use //span[text()='Vehicle']//preceding::a  to click the tag **a** instead

Comment: @J.Lyu : **`//span[text()='Vehicle']//preceding::a`** -> This won't work because `preceding` here signifies the direct preceding sibling element `a` of `span` tag, but `a` element here is the parent of the concerned `span` tag. So, the xpath to use shall be **`//span[text()='Vehicle']/..`** which will return the immediate parent tag/element of the concerned `span` element, which in this case is `a`.

Comment: @Subh Yeah **//span[text()='Vehicle']/..** is totally right but I am gonna to say that preceding is not searching sibling element.  It will get the right element if  there is no other **a** tag before the concerned span's parent

Comment: i just checked ..there is no javascript triggering on vehicle option. and i also tested with   //span[text()='Vehicle']/.. ..this line of code is not working

Comment: @J.Lyu : Oh! Yes.. Sorry.. My bad. For some wierd reason, I imagined the presence of `sibling` suffixed besides `preceding`.. :) 
@RahilKumar : Is the concerned element in a frame or something?

Comment: @Subh : it is normal Tab section. no frame

Comment: @Subh@J.Lyu :  i also added Below line of code
 Actions act = new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Vehicle']")));
 act.build().perform();

but there is no action happening

Comment: @FranMontero :  there is no javascript action on tab

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix 'Source not found' error when debugging in Eclipse, using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708651/how-do-i-fix-source-not-found-error-when-debugging-in-eclipse-using-selenium)

Comment: @RahilKumar : **(Taken from the advise of @J.Lyu)** Please try this code, and let me know what value is getting returned here : `System.out.println("The id of Vehicle is: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Vehicle']/..")).getAttribute("id"));` Need to know, if the element is even getting located or not.

Comment: @Subh :  I wrote a line of code which you mentioned but i am getting compile time error

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 - Line breakpoint:FirstProgram [line: 41] -

Comment: @RahilKumar: Some problem with IDE while copying, I guess.. Do one thing.. Just type it out. You should be fine.

Comment: @Subh i did ..The code Executed but didn't return anything. the Output was

"The id of Vehicle is:"

Comment: @RahilKumar: Oh. I think there are multiple elements involved in this case. In firebug, when you enter this xpath, how many matching nodes do you get ?

Comment: @Subh ok . I searched for "//span[text()='Vehicle']" in firepath I got 3 matching nodes


I tired with below line of code but got "No Matching FOund Node"

//input[@span="Vehicle"][@class="ajax__tab_tab"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88561/discussion-between-subh-and-rahil-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's comments, I am posting the xpaths that can be used to locate the concerned element :

1- `//span[@id='MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle_tab']//span[.='Vehicle']`

This will locate the `span` element with innerHTML/text as **Vehicle** which is a descendant of `span` with **id** `MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle_tab`

OR

2-`//span[@id='MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle_tab']//span[.='Vehicle']/..`

This will locate the **parent** of `span` element with innerHTML/text as **Vehicle** which is a descendant of `span` with **id** `MainContentPlaceHolder_tbCntrViewCase_tbPnlVehicle_tab` which in this case is an `a` element.

Please check if this works for you. Else, let me know how many matching nodes does it show, when you use them. We will sort this one out.

Comment: I tried with above Codes. both are able to inspect elements in firebug.. but when i am Executing in Eclipse IDE then i am getting NoSuchElement FOund Exception
I also Recorded the testcase in Selenium IDE and extracted the code....there also I got same exception

Comment: I attached screen shot of tabs. please check it out once